# Variance and expected value of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let X be a random variable over the integers $Z=\ldots,−2,−1,0,1,2,\ldots$

Let $P(X=0)=0$ and for $i≠0$ let $P(X=i)= \frac{1}{Z_α|i|^α}$ where $Z_α = ∑_{i=−∞}^{∞}\frac{1}{|i|^α}$.

I am trying to find the value for $E[X]$, $var[X]$, and $std[X]$ for different values of $\alpha$. I know that $P(X=i)$ is a probability distribution as $∑_{i=−∞}^{∞}P(X=i) = \frac{∑_{i=−∞}^{∞}\frac{1}{|i|^α}}{∑_{i=−∞}^{∞}\frac{1}{|i|^α}}=1$. However, I have no clue where to start this problem. My intuition is, because $P(X=i) = 1 $ for all $i$, E[X] is just the summation of the numbers in $Z$. This would give me an expected value of 0 for all values of $\alpha$; however, this is incorrect. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect statement in question: $P(x=i)=1 \, \forall i$

Correct statement: $P(x\neq0) = 1$

$E(X) = \sum\limits_{x \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}} xP(x) = \sum\limits_{x \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}}x \frac{1}{Z_{\alpha}|x|^\alpha} = \sum\limits_{x \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}^{+}-\{0\}}x \frac{1}{Z_{\alpha}|x|^\alpha} - \sum\limits_{x \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}^{+}-\{0\}}x \frac{1}{Z_{\alpha}|x|^\alpha} = 0$

$V(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$

$V(X) = \sum\limits_{x \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}} x^2P(x) = \sum\limits_{x \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}}x^2 \frac{1}{Z_{\alpha}|x|^\alpha} = \sum\limits_{x \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}} \frac{1}{Z_{\alpha}|x|^{\alpha-2}} = \frac{Z_{\alpha-2}}{Z_{\alpha}}$

$std(X) = \sqrt{V(X)}$

Comment: But if $\alpha = 2$, then E[X] can't equal 0, right?

Comment: Why not? The above proof is a general proof. You can visualize this also. Think of a real line with integers marked on it. Now, corresponding to each integer make a vertical line above the x-axis of height equal to the probability of that integer. This is the plot of probability mass function. Now, note that both $i$ and $-i$ will have same probability mass (vertical line of same height) as per the definition of your probability mass function $P(x=i)$.